# Android: Decrease price for active subscription does require user consent?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I'm a bit lost in the docs for google play subscription price change: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#change-price-sub
While reading this section one could think that every price change requires a user consent or only increasing the price of an active subscription (like Apple does)

Has anyone made a subscription price reduction and can tell how Google Play behaves?

Comment: I did price reduction for subscription and I can say that even if user need to approve it, they wont be angry about it, at least I did not faced with any problems :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The play store behaves the same wether you increase or decrease the price of the subscription.

This means, that the play store will send the user an e-mail with the details, the mail contains a button which will direct the user into the store to confirm the price change.

If the user does not react to the e-mail the play store will send a notification via the play store app with the details of the price change. The notifacation will link to the subscription details in the play store where the user can confirm the price changes.

But before the play store will send a notification, you have 7 days to inform your users yourself if you want to. You can do this by either:

- Start a `priceChangeConfirmationFlow` which displays a dialog within your app. [more info](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#communicate-sub-price-change)
- Send the user to the subscription details page of the play store via intent [more info](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#deep-links-manage-subs)

If the user does not accept the price change before his/her current subscription expires, the subscription will get cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed a bit since this has been answered. Especially if you are decreasing the price. From the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#price-change):

> - Google Play begins notifying your users of the price change starting seven days after confirmation.
> - When increasing subscription price, users must approve of the price change within 30 days, or their subscription is automatically cancelled.
> - *Subscription price decreases are applied automatically for existing subscribers at their next renewal date. Anyone who subscribes after a price decrease receives the decreased price automatically.*